# Визулизация дерева

Tags: graph, c, opengl

Стоит задача визуализировать дерево. Дерево классическое: каждый узел имеет не больше 1 родителя. Количество детей считается рандомно, в соответствии с заданным числом. Вывести нужно поуровнево. Для визуализации решил попробовать метод пружин, как он описан [здесь](http://masters.donntu.edu.ua/2011/fknt/levzhinsky/library/tez1.htm) (формула для подсчета силы, действующей на узел).

Естественную длину пружины беру равной расстоянию между уровнями. Расстояние между связанными узлами вычисляю по теореме Пифагора.

Вопрос в следующем: я не совсем могу понять, каким образом выбирать коэффициент жесткости и коэффициент силы отталкивания.

Пишу я на C + OpenGL. Попробовал смоделировать приход системы в состояние равновесия. При генерации дерева в самом начале задаются рандомные координаты по оси X. Затем по таймеру меняется коэффициент жесткости и коэффициент отталкивания, вычисляются новые координаты и происходит перерисовка дерева.

Функция таймера выглядит примерно следующим образом:

```
static float sumE;
static float k = 0;
static float ot = 0;

...

void timef(int value)
{
    do 
    {
         p_Fe = sumE;
         // stabilization считает новые координаты в соответствии с k и ot
         // и возвращает суммарную энергию системы
         sumE = stabilization(tree->root);
    } while (abs(p_Fe - sumE) > 100);

    k += -0.0005 / 0.9; // Коэффициент жесткости (просто подогнал)
    ot -= 100;          // Коэффициент отталкивания (просто подогнал)

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(100, timef, 0);
}
```

В результате что-то да получается. Условно, граф отрисовывается хорошо. Вот примеры отрисовки:
[Рис. 1](http://s017.radikal.ru/i419/1410/1c/8ede8ca88e0c.png)
[Рис. 2](http://i072.radikal.ru/1410/00/57e6b1dd9f94.png)

На висячие узлы не обращайте внимание, просто они колеблятся относительно своего родителя. Но, правда, отсюда возникает ещё одна проблема. Все узлы нумеруются сквозным способом (на рис. видно), и не хотелось бы, чтобы порядок висячих узлов менялся. Как это учитывать, второй вопрос)

Если взглянуть, видно, что, например, на Рис. 1 площадь графа можно было бы уменьшить, т.е. расстояние между узлами на 2 уровне могло быть и меньше. На втором рисунке также. Иногда, если звезды сходятся, то коэффициенты подходят для текущего дерева, и оно отрисовывается хорошо.

Влияние коэффициентов вроде бы правильно. То есть при увеличении жесткости по модулю расстояние между узлами уменьшается. При увеличении коэффициента отталкивания расстояние между узлами увеличивается. Но, естественно, для каждого дерева требуется свои варианты жесткости и отталкивания.

Причем, если взглянуть на рисунки, слева сверху написаны текущие коэффициент жесткости и отталкивания и видно, что они довольно сильно разнятся, даже очень сильно. Но именно при таком большом коэффициенте отталкивания узлы более-менее встают на свои места. Даже если занулить жесткость. А вот коэффициент жесткости должен быть, как правило, очень маленьким. Если он выходит за -1, то все вершины отправляются куда-то на Марс %) и вообще кустики дерева начинают жить своей жизнью, куда-то ходят, не могут решиться в какую сторону пойти и так далее)))

Вот и встал вопрос: из каких соображений вообще считать эти коэффициенты для текущего дерева так, чтобы площадь была минимальной и всем узлам хватало места.